# ADSI Search for DistinguishedName of the primary group based on primarygroupid

Tags: powershell, adsi

Because we don't have the active directory module available on all our systems we're using `ADSI` instead. The following code retrieves a user object from AD by using the `AdsiSearcher`:

```
$ADUser = ([AdsiSearcher]"(samaccountname=$SamAccountName)").FindOne()
```

This results in finding the property `primarygroupid` which represents the domain primary group for user, usually number `513`. When we have this number we would like to find the `distinguishedName` of the group. However, the code below does that just fine I was wondering if there is a better `filter` that can be used instead of filtering after the `FindAll()` method?

```
    $searcher = [adsisearcher]'objectclass=group'
    $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('primarygrouptoken')
    $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('distinguishedName')
    $searcher.FindAll() |
    Where-Object { $_.Properties.primarygrouptoken -eq 513}
```

Something like this would be great but it's not possible:

```
([adsisearcher]”(&(objectCategory=group)(primaryGroupid=513))”).FindOne()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with trying to pass variable into \[adsisearcher\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623958/issue-with-trying-to-pass-variable-into-adsisearcher)

Comment: It's not related as I am looking to filter on the property that contains the number `513`. I am well aware of how to use variables just not if it's possible to filter on this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `primaryGroupToken` is a *constructed* attribute, meaning that it's not actually materialized in the database, and can't be filtered using LDAP.

In order to build an equivalent filter we'll need to look at how it is *constructed* - and the primary group token in Active Directory is always the same as the group's RID part (the *relative identifier*) of the `objectSid` attribute.

So, if we want to search by it, we can simply filter by `objectSid` instead:

```
# Obtain domain SID
$dncDN = ([adsi]"LDAP://RootDSE").defaultNamingContext
$dnc = [adsi]"LDAP://$dncDN"
$domainSID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($dnc.objectSid.Value, 0)

# Set the group ID we're looking for
$RID = 513

# Search for group by objectSid value:
([adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=group)(objectSid=${domainSID}-${RID}))").FindOne()
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias this was exactly what I was looking for. I already found it strange to use `FindAll()` as it takes longer than `FindOne()` and was unnecessary in this case.