# ldap search filter to check if any user exists under specific domain

Tags: go, debugging, search, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to validate if there is one user at least under specific domain using ldap search.

I used this filter, but do not have any match:

```
dc=example,dc=com sub (&(objectClass=user)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)) 
(sAMAccountName=*))
```

once I try this, it has a match:

```
dc=example,dc=com sub (&(objectClass=user)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)) 
(sAMAccountName=Admini*))
```

Can you help me on this please.

Comment: maybe ``*`` on it's own isn't the correct pattern for a filter.  It isn't a valid regular expression for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [RFC2254](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2254) does have '*' wildcard pattern defined for "String Representation of LDAP Search Filters".

But it might not be implemented by all LDAP server.
A Go LDAP server like [`nmcclain/ldap`](https://github.com/nmcclain/ldap) should [support it](https://github.com/nmcclain/ldap#a-simple-ldap-search-operation)

But as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9575655/6309), a '*' search might simply time out (because if would take too long to complete)